# Conditions for a Negative Semi-definite Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

probably it is a dumb question but I want to know if having the diagonal elements of a matrix is enough to say that matrix is negative semi definite. Or should i find if the determinant is nonnegative? Also, are there any circumstances where negative diagonal elements are enough and others where we have to find the determinant to be greater or equal than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having negative diagonal entries is not enough to guarantee that a matrix is negative definite. As a counterexample, consider
$$
\pmatrix{-1&2\\2&-1}.
$$
However, if a matrix has negative diagonal entries and is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), then we can in fact conclude that this matrix is negative definite.

Note that computing the determinant of the matrix is not generally enough to ensure that the matrix is negative definite. The standard test using determinants is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) (which is geared towards the strictly negative definite case, but can be adjusted to handle the negative semidefinite case).